# "Жвачка" во множественном числе

Tags: грамотная-речь, морфология

Скажите, пожалуйста, можно ли сказать "жвачки", когда речь идет о множественном числе, или все равно будет "жвачка"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Жвачка" в значении "жевательная резинка" вполне может иметь множественное число, поскольку речь идет о штучном объекте. Впрочем, даже этот факт штучности не является обязательным. Сравните: много стекла - много стёкол. Разговорность значения никак не сказывается на логике.

В отношении множественного для других значений слова - не уверен. Сомнительно...

Answer (score 1):

Ед. ч. ЖВАЧКА, мн. ч. ЖВАЧКИ. Н-р: У меня есть хорошая *жвачка*. У меня много *жвачек*. Слово "много" требует мн. ч. Р. п.  Много (чего?) жвач**ек**, собач**ек**, птич**ек**.
Не все то,  что говорят, правильно.  Есть нормы рус. яз., но к норме не относится разговорная речь.

Comment: А я, помню, слышал, что где-то по телевизору говорили "у меня много жвачки". Или это неправильно?

Comment: Вполне правильно. А почему такой вывод о неправильности?